# String property behaves really weird

Tags: c#, string, properties

I have a settings class like this:

```
public class Settings
{
    string resourcePath;
    public string ResourcePath {
        get {
            return resourcePath + "/";
        }
        set {
            resourcePath = value;
        }
    }

    string texturePath;
    public string TexturePath {
        get {
            string a = resourcePath + "/"; // This is just some debug stuff I did trying to find out wtf is going on
            string b = texturePath + "/";
            return a + b; // Breakpointing here shows that it is "Content/Textures/"
        }
        set {
            texturePath = value;
        }
    }

    public Settings ()
    {
        resourcePath = "Content";
        texturePath = "Textures";
    }

    public static Settings CurrentSettings = new Settings();
}
```

Then I try to get the TexturePath from it, like this:

```
string path = Settings.CurrentSettings.TexturePath + file;
```

The string returned by the property is `"Content//Content/Textures//"`

What am I missing here? Why does it do that? With my knowledge it should return `Content/Textures/`

Comment: Think you might need to post some more of your code - nothing in what you've posted to explain what you're seeing...

Comment: It doesn't do it on my machine. Are you showing all your code?

Comment: The error is not in the provided code. See [sample here](http://ideone.com/rYN4f3). Also, use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to create a path from its components.

Comment: I think some other code is changing the static `CurrentSettings`

Comment: Are you sure it's `string a = resourcePath + "/";`, not `string a = ResourcePath + "/";` with the upper case "R"?

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint on the setters and verify that they don't already get a *value* that has the / appended.

Comment: Ah yes. I am indeed writing the default Settings to xml file, and then I read it from there, and TexturePath is Content/Textures/ in the XML file since it is written there like that.

Comment: I missed that because I did not try to see the next breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be balancing the `/` between the getter and the setter. And you probably are getting some property and then setting another with it - resulting in too many `/`'s.

Comment: Your answer was the one that got me thinking more, and I figured I should try to see the next breakpoint. Thanks. I will mark this accepted after the cooldown limit is gone.

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to work with path.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Settings.CurrentSettings.TexturePath,file);
```

and no need to add "/" to your properties.

```
public string ResourcePath {
    get {
        return resourcePath;
    }
    set {
        resourcePath = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will use this approach from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the code that produces the results you reported but the following code is highly suspect:

```
string resourcePath;
public string ResourcePath {
    get {
        return resourcePath + "/";
    }
    set {
        resourcePath = value;
    }
}
```

It always appends a forward slash on the getter but never removes it in the setter. So the following code:

```
x.ResourcePath = "abc";
x.ResourcePath = x.ResourcePath + "/def";
x.ResourcePath = x.ResourcePath + "/ghi";
```

Would set `ResourcePath` to "abc//def//ghi".

I suspect you are running into something like that.